# Processing huge amount of data on a small python script

Tags: python

Hello i have a small python script its job is to read data from a TXT file and sort it in a specific remove duplicate and remove none sense data and put it back in another TXT file this format MAC IP Number Device

```
import re
f = open('frame.txt', 'r')
d = open('Result1.txt', 'w')
mac=""
ip=""
phoneName=""
phoneTel=""
lmac=""
lip=""
lphoneName=""
lphoneTel=""
lines=f.readlines()
s=0
p=0
for line in lines:
    matchObj = re.search( '(?<=Src: )[0-9a-z]{2}:[0-9a-z]{2}:[0-9a-z]{2}:[0-9a-z]{2}:[0-9a-z]{2}:[0-9a-z]{2}', line, re.M|re.I)
    if(matchObj):
            mac=matchObj.group(0)+"\t"
    matchObj = re.search( '(?<=Src: )([0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line, re.M|re.I)
    if(matchObj):
            ip=matchObj.group(0)+"\t"
    if(s==1):
        s=0
        matchObj = re.search( '(?<=Value: )\d+',line,re.M|re.I)
        if(matchObj):
            phoneName=matchObj.group(0)+"\t"
    if(p==1):
        p=0
        matchObj = re.search( '(?<=Value: ).+',line,re.M|re.I)
        if(matchObj):
            phoneTel=matchObj.group(0)+"\t"  
    matchObj = re.search( '(?<=Key: user \(218)', line, re.M|re.I)
    if(matchObj):
        s=1
    matchObj = re.search( '(?<=Key: resource \(165)', line, re.M|re.I)
    if(matchObj):
        p=1
    if(mac!="" and ip!="" and phoneName!="" and phoneTel!="" and mac!=lmac and ip!=lip and phoneName!=lphoneName and phoneTel!=lphoneTel):        
        d.write(mac+" " +ip+" "+ phoneName+" "+ phoneTel)
        lmac=mac
        lip=ip
        lphoneName=phoneName
        lphoneTel=phoneTel
        d.write("\n")
    matchObj = re.search( 'Frame \d+', line, re.M|re.I)
    if(matchObj):              
        mac=""
        ip=""
        phoneName=""
        phoneTel=""        
d.close()
f.close()
```

here the code the problem is that the code need to process HUGE amount of data that might reach 100GB and when I'm doing so the program freezes and kill itself any idea how to fix this problem thank you so much!

Comment: Sounds like a job for `awk`. What does your file look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reading the entire file at the start - if the file is that large, loading it into memory will be a problem.  Try iterating over the lines instead.  Generally, you'd like

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        # This will iterate over the lines in the file rather than read them all at once
```

So for you, change your loop construction to:

```
for line in f:
```

and remove:

```
lines=f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

use readline() instead of readlines()

readlines() reads whole file to memory at once.